# Most general gyroscope motion

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes

In Kleppner & Kolenkow's [*Introduction to Mechanics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521198119) (Amazon link), the general gyroscope motion including [nutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation) was derived using the approximation condition $\Omega T \ll 1$ where $\Omega$ is the precession angular velocity and $T$ is the period of nutation.

How does one describe the gyroscopic motion if the the condition for the approximation is not satisfied? How does one describe the general gyroscopic motion if

1. the angular momentum of precession is not negligible and
2. if the gyroscope spins very slowly around its axis, $\omega$ is low?

In general I want to find the formula for most general gyroscope motion. If I let $\omega$ go to zero then I should get the special case of a pendulum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Describing a motion of gyroscope with gimbal](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107711/)

Comment: See also related post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80449/392

Comment: I actually think this may not be a duplicate, since the other question is just asking how to describe ordinary gyroscopic motion, whereas this one is asking how to go beyond that and relax the assumption that $\Omega T\ll 1$. (Besides, this question is _much_ better phrased than that one.)

Comment: @DavidZ: Thanks for recognizing that my question is different. Have you also got some clue or an answer for me?